# How can I make the spacing between Divs in my website consistent, regardless of content amount within the divs

Tags: html, css, margins

I am trying to make multiple pages of the same website with different content on each page. For instance I want each page to have the same look and feel, The spacing between each divs to be exact  regardless of the content. I tried to use display: inline-block; to autofit the divs and use a margins for the spacing.

I am also using absolute positioning on the divs inside a fixed container.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you can use the bootstrap to load the div such that it remain the same for every page using the predefined class .col-md-x

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `<div class="space">A</div>` with the div tag being white, white borders, white text.

You need to do that because someone could put their default color to **BLACK**. Also, change the css:

```
div.space {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

so it will have the same position of the letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your stylesheet

```
div { margin: 10px 0}
```

this is give you a top and bottom margin of 10px between each div.  You can use whatever px amount you want instead on 10.